# How to use the factory pattern with functors?

Tags: c++, templates, factory, functor

I have a set of functors for calculating specific stuff on ranges on objects. Essentially, each functor implements `operator()`:

```
template <typename Iterator1,
          typename Iterator2> double operator()( Iterator1 it1,
                                                 Iterator2 it2 ) const
{
  return( 0.0 );
}
```

I now have a set of objects that can be *created* with different functors. I solved this by templating the creator function:

```
template <class Functor> Foo createFoo( ... // some parameters for foo objects
                                        Functor f = Functor() )
{
  // calculate stuff for "foo" using functor "f"
}
```

I now want to *delegate* functor selection to the user of my program, so I decided to create a functor factory. Given a descriptive name of a functor, I want to create the appropriate functor so that it can be used in the creation of all `Foo` objects, as above.

This is where I get stuck, though: I cannot create a factory that returns a templated functor because I cannot call this function without coding the exact type of functor I want to create.

I thought about making `operator()` a virtual function of some base class, i.e. `FunctorBase`, but I don't want the performance overhead associated with virtual function calls. Avoiding said overhead was why I chose to use templates in the first place.

I am at an impasse here and would sure appreciate some comments.

**EDIT**:

What I intend to do (invalid code):

```
DistanceFunctor f = createFunctor( "Bar" ); // Create a functor from a client-supplied string

Foo createFoo( ..., // parameters for foo
               f );
```

In the comments, the use of virtual functions was suggested as well. The current functor design as described above would not work with virtual functions, though, because the compiler cannot make function templates virtual. Adjusting the functor class to take two Iterator types as template parameters would be possible, but very clunky.

**EDIT**:

The functors work similar to the ones used in FLANN. [See the git repository for an example](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/blob/master/src/cpp/flann/algorithms/dist.h). I don't see how to specify these functors any differently.

Comment: Can you show how you intend to use all these functions together?

Comment: Is that "performance overhead" measurable? Do the virtual function calls hurt so much, i.e. did a profiler tell you that they are a crucial performance bottleneck? Or are you making your life just a little bit harder doing premature optimization?

Comment: @ArneMertz: I have not yet implemented the other variant. I figured that if each functor is being applied to several million objects, virtual functions might slow me down. Thus: You may be right :-/

I will implement the other variant and report back with some results.

Comment: @ArneMertz Stupid me: Since each functor contains a function template, I cannot use `virtual`. At least not in the way I described it here.

Comment: What does `DistanceFunctor` do? The first signature you provided seems like it does somehow accumulate values from a range of objects or something similar. Maybe you don't need a functor iterating over the range, but a predicate that you can pass into `createFoo` and use it in some algorithm that iterates over the range (e.g. `std::accumulate`).

Comment: @ArneMertz It calculates distances between ranges of objects. For example, one functor will calculate the absolute distance between each pair of values described by both iterators. In my implementation, the functor also has an attribute that specifies how many elements are to be used from both ranges. The closest example I could find was something like the [`L2_simple` functor in FLANN](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/blob/master/src/cpp/flann/algorithms/dist.h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having thought a bit about your requrements, this is the first thing that I came up with:
Your different functors obviously cannot be derived from a common base class the way they are defined now, since you can't make the templated `operator()` virtual. But you *can* make that operator virtual if you push the template parameters away from the operator, up to the functor itself:

```
template <class Iterator>
struct Functor {
  virtual double operator()(Iterator it1, Iterator it2) const = 0;
};
```

How does that help? Having the template at the Functor level at first sight does not look good, since you now will have to know the parameter outside the call of `createFunctor`, in fact, you will have to explicitly specify the iterator type if you call it:

```
//some concrete functors
template <class It>
struct FuncImpl_Bar : Functor<It> { /* ... implement op()(It, It) ... */ }:

template <class It>
struct FuncImpl_Meow : Functor<It> { /* ... implement op()(It, It) ... */ }:

template <class Iterator>
std::shared_ptr<Functor<Iterator>> createFunctor(std::string const& str)
{
  if (str == "Bar") return std::make_shared<FuncImpl_Bar<Iterator>>(/* args *);
  else return return std::make_shared<FuncImpl_Meow<Iterator>>(/* args *);
}

//...
auto MyFunctor = createFunctor<???>("Bar"); //what iterator type???
```

But AFAICS you don't nee to know the exact type of the functor outside `createFoo` - it's sufficient if `createFoo` knows that type:

```
Foo createFoo( ... // some parameters for foo objects
                                        std::string const& str ) //look mum, no templates!
{
  typedef whatever_the_container_i_use::iterator Iter;
  Functor<Iter> MyFunctor = createFunctor<Iter>(str);
  // calculate stuff for "foo" using functor "f"
}

//...
auto myFoo = createFoo(args, "Bar");
auto myOtherFoo = createFoo(args, "Moo");
```

In short: pass the factory parameter down to the point where you know the Iterator type, i.e. the type you have to parametrize the functor factory with. Call the factory where you know *every* input needed, i.e. type and nontype arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution. I am now thinking about rewriting this design, as your solution clearly demonstrated some shortcomings in my initial design. Thanks for your input :)